# Let $X$ be a nonempty set and let $f:X \to \Bbb R$ be such that $f[X]:=\{f(x): x \in X\}$ is a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and let $f:X \to \Bbb R$ be such that $f[X]:=\{f(x): x \in X \}$ is a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$.

Prove that for any $a \in \Bbb R$:

$$ \sup \{a+f(x):x \in X\} = a+ \sup(f[X]). $$

My attempt so far:

$\sup \{a+f(x):x \in X\} = a + \sup f[X]$

$\sup \{ a+f(x):x \in X\} = a + \sup \{f(x):x \in X\}$

But now I'm confused? What is the sup of $\{f(x):x \in X\}$?  How do I complete the proof? My prof doesn't do any examples so this is super difficult so if you could explain how you did it that'd be amazing.

Comment: $f[X]$ can be any bounded non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$. What you need to show is that if $Y$ is a bounded non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ and $a\in \Bbb R$ then $a+\sup Y=\sup (a+Y)$ where $a+Y=\{a+y:y\in Y\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to work with the definition: the suppremum is the smallest upper bound.

1. **$a+\sup f(X)$ is an upper bound for $\sup \{a+f(x):x\in X\}$**. This should be obvious, since $a+f(x) \leq a+\sup f(X)$.
2. **$a+\sup f(X)$ is the smallest upper bound**. Well, from the definition of $\sup f(X)$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_\varepsilon \in X$ such that $f(x_\varepsilon)>\sup f(X)-\varepsilon$. Now you just add $a$ to each one of the sides:
   $$ a+f(x_\varepsilon)>(a+\sup f(X))-\varepsilon$$
   This shows that indeed $a+\sup f(X)$ is the smallest upper bound for $\{a+f(x):x \in X\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So the idea is to just use the definitions to prove stuff? This is my first proof based class so this is still a work in progress.

Comment: Well, for basic results like this, there really is no simpler starting point than the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the *definition* of the supremum of a (bounded) set as the minimum of all upper bounds for a set.

By assumption $f[X]$ is bounded in the reals so $s:= \sup(f[X])$ is a well-defined real number (by order completeness of $\Bbb R$).

Now if $x \in X$, $f(x) \in f[X]$ so $f(x) \le s$, as $s$ is an upper bound for $f[X]$ by definition. But then $a+f(x) \le a+s$ too, and as $x \in X$ is arbitary (!),  $a+s$ is an upperbound for $\{a + f(x): x \in x\}$ and $\sup \{a + f(x): x \in x\}$ is the minimum of the set of that set's upperbounds, so

$$\sup \{a + f(x): x \in x\} \le a+s\tag{1}$$

has been shown.

Now suppose that $L$ is any upperbound for the set $\{a + f(x): x \in X\}$.
I'll show that $L-a$ is an upperbound for $f[X]$: let $x \in X$, then $a + f(x) \in \{a + f(x): x \in X\}$ so $a+f(x) \le L$, as $L$ is an upperbound, 
and so (subtracting $a$ from both sides preserves the order) $f(x) \le L-a$. As $s = \sup\{ f(x): x \in X\}$ is the smallest of all upperbounds for $f[X]$ we again conclude that $s \le L-a$ or equivalently:

$$a+s \le a+(L-a) = L\tag{2}$$

So $a+ s = a + \sup(f[X])$ is smaller than *any* arbitary upperbound $L$ of $\{a + f(x): x \in X\}$ and so is its supremum (from (1) and (2) together). QED

Comment: Typos: It should be $x\in X,$ not $x\in x.$

Comment: @Matematleta Thx. Typo followed by copy-paste :)

Comment: Thank you a ton. This is my first proof based class so I'm still learning I appreciate the help.

Comment: @ChadOfMath336 Glad to help. An upvote would be nice :)